# date between query does not return exact result

Tags: mysql

This query does not return the records on jan , but it return records on feb

```
SELECT EventAsstCharged,CustomerName,EventID ,EventName,EventExpectedCharges,EventActuallyCharged,EventUserCharged,date_format(EventDate,'%d-%m-%Y') as EventDate ,EventTime 
FROM tblevent 
WHERE Status=1 AND date_format(EventDate,'%d-%m-%Y') between '01-01-2011' AND '20-02-2011' AND EntryUser=2 AND Status=1 
ORDER BY EventID DESC
```

EventDate is the DATE type

Comment: Calling `date_format` for the dates is redundant, or already the root of your problem.

Comment: have you tried `EventDate between '2011-01-01' and '2011-02-20'` ?

Comment: SELECT EventAsstCharged,CustomerName,EventID ,EventName,EventExpectedCharges,EventActuallyCharged,EventUserCharged,date_format(EventDate,'%d-%m-%Y') as EventDate ,EventTime FROM tblevent WHERE Status=1 AND EventDate between '01-01-2011' AND '20-02-2011' AND EntryUser=2 AND Status=1 ORDER BY EventID DESC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL's date format is `YYYY-MM-DD`. Try

```
EventDate between '2011-01-01' AND '2011-20-02'
```